# Code to Graph XYZ coordinates

Tags: c++, swing, unix, graph, 3d

I need to graph XYZ coordinates in a 3D cube that I can rotate. Im look for code that will basically take a 3d array of 1s and 0s and build a cube. Coloring of the points would also be nice. The program that creates the point is in C/C++ so I would prefer something that would play nicely will that but Im not picky. Im alright aware that Mathematica can do this , but Im looking for something that can be "live" updated so I can watch the progress
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

One obvious possibility would be something like Direct3D (for Windows, X-box and Windows Phone 7) or OpenGL (for pretty much anything that can do 3D except X-box or Windows Phone 7).

There are quite a few libraries and [sample code](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/g-m/opengl/article.php/c5575/Selectable-3-D-Scattergraph-Using-OpenGL.htm) for things like this.

If you're working on Unix/Linux, you may or may not have OpenGL installed. If you don't, you might want to check into [Mesa3D](http://mesa3d.org).

Comment: +1 for OpenGL. Much easier to get something basic going with it

Answer (score 0):

I would go with Jerry's suggestion of using OpenGL. There are some good tutorials out there too - have a look at [the nehe series](http://nehe.gamedev.net/lesson.asp?index=01) which have examples for doing precisely what you're after.

Answer (score -1):

Refer this tutorial link : http://www.directxtutorial.com/

This will help you to implement three dimensional cube.

Comment: It is paywalled